# Only want results of those that are active to show in query. PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am a new MySQL and PHP coder... used to work with it a about 7 years ago but now it has fallen in my lap again.  Currently the code pulls students for attendance tracking and works like this:

```
$count = sqlValue("SELECT count(*) FROM `attendance` LEFT JOIN `enrollments` ON attendance.`student_class` = enrollments.id Where enrollments.class='".$class."' AND attendance.date='".$date."'");
    if ($count == 0)
    {       
        $query = "SELECT CONCAT_WS('', `students`.`fname`, ' ', `students`.`lname`)  as `student`, `classes`.`class_name` as class, enrollments.id as eid FROM `students` LEFT JOIN `enrollments` ON students.id = enrollments.student LEFT JOIN `classes` ON classes.id = enrollments.class";
        $query.= " WHERE enrollments.class='".$class."'";
        $query.= " ORDER BY students.id";

        $res   = sql($query, $eo);
        $tbody = '';$ids=array();
        if(db_num_rows($res) > 0)
```

This works great but now they only want to show those that are "Active".  I added a column to the database and coded the front end to flag the student as active.  All this works, now I want to run a query that will only show the active students, which will then let me use a check box to mark them as present for the class.  I have tried the following, but it did not work:

```
$count = sqlValue("SELECT count(*) FROM `attendance` LEFT JOIN `enrollments` ON attendance.`student_class` = enrollments.id Where enrollments.class='".$class."' AND attendance.date='".$date."'");
    if ($count == 0)
    {       
        $query = "SELECT CONCAT_WS('', `students`.`fname`, ' ', `students`.`lname`)  as `student`, `classes`.`class_name` as class, enrollments.id as eid FROM `students` LEFT JOIN `enrollments` ON students.id = enrollments.student LEFT JOIN `classes` ON classes.id = enrollments.class";
        $query.= " WHERE enrollments.class='".$class."'" and enrollments.status <> 'Active';
        $query.= " ORDER BY students.id";

        $res   = sql($query, $eo);
        $tbody = '';$ids=array();
        if(db_num_rows($res) > 0)
```

It throws an error on line 45 which is the `$query.= " WHERE enrollments.class='".$class."'" and enrollments.status <> 'Active';` line.

Structure is

```
    Table structure for table `enrollments`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `enrollments` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `student` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `class` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `enrollment_date` date NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `student` (`student`),
  KEY `class` (`class`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=109 ;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: please post table structure.

Comment: Which error does it show?

Comment: Look at the highlighting in your question - you have too many quotes in your code. `$class."'"` should be `$class."'`; though you might want to look at using a prepared statement instead.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'ORDER' (T_STRING)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an additional quotation mark in `"'"`.

The line should read:

```
     $query.= " WHERE enrollments.class='".$class."' and enrollments.status <> 'Active'";
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'ORDER' (T_STRING) in /home/job2/public_html/jobfix/filter.php on line 45

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the quotation mark at the end. Fixed now.

Comment: NP, The error code is gone, but now it is pulling everyone (as it did before), not just those with Active status.

Comment: I really appreciate the assist on this syck!

Comment: Nope, it retrieves those where the `enrollments.status` is **different** from `Active`.

Comment: Gotcha...thats perfect!  I adjusted the code accordingly.  Thanks big time syck!